# use github webhook on FTP shared server

Tags: php, git, github, ftp, webhooks

I want to deploy a website stored on github to a shared server from OVH. So, basically, after each push I would like the new code to auto-deploy on my server.

I read [this article](http://jefaisvotresite.com/blog/article/deployer-automatiquement-son-site-sur-un-ftp-mutualise-avec-git-et-bitbucket) (in french, sorry). To sum it up, it explains how to do it with BitBucket. They provide a php file to put on your server. Then, you make BitBucket send a POST request on that file, and it's over. [Here](https://gist.github.com/RomainSauvaire/5320749) is the code of that php file.

My only trouble is that I know nothing about php and that file is made for BitBucket and not GitHub. But I think it should be easy to make it work with GitHub. The only line to change should be that one :

```
        $url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories".$uri."raw/".$node."/".$file->file;
```

Instead of BitBucket I should adapt for GitHub... But I have no idea of what I should write instead...

Could anyone help me with that ?

Comment: I'm currently looking into doing this with GitHub and using the default "Push" webhook to make a HTTP post to a payload URL. The information on how to do it is here https://developer.github.com/webhooks/. Quite straightforward on how to do it via SSH as this tutorial explains http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh--net-19564. My issues is that I need to use SOAP.

Comment: I have managed to do this successfully. Are you still having trouble with this?

Comment: Hum... More or less. Right now I rely on DeployHQ. As my project is open-source, I got a free licence. It's fine for now, but I'd rather be independent if I can. What is your solution ?